# My player(cube) is only sliding to the right I need it to slide when I click D, how do I fix this

Tags: c#

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody Rb;

    public float forwardForce = 2000f;
   
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

            if (Input.GetKey("d")) ;
        {
            Rb.AddForce(500 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You are aplying a force in the X axis when you press the D key, what is your problem? Please, clarify your question.

Comment: The semicolon at the end of the line of the If-statement (`if (Input.GetKey("d")) ;`) makes the if-statement do nothing (it "ends" the if-statement). You should remove the semicolon on that line.